# How to list one package on both the English and Japanese AppExchange marketplaces?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, appexchange, 2gp, packaging

We are attempting to list our App on the Japanese App exchange. We have successfully listed on the English App exchange; the App has passed its security review recently. (The term "marketplace" is used in some for the documentation to describe these two instances.)

The problem is that we cannot find the package listed in the App in tab for the Japanese marketplace. The help text says:

> ... same package cannot be used on multiple listings. (this includes
> all versions)

How then can we list our App on both marketplaces?

(Wondering if this is a core requirement of how the multiple marketplaces work, or just a bug where the listings being in different marketplaces isn't taken into account in the UI.)

Do we ned to create another package for the same App using packaging 2 i.e. single namespace, same components, but included in two different package Ids? [That is possible](https://medium.com/@bobmatt3/salesforce-2gp-share-a-single-namespace-with-multiple-packages-cd5c6317384), but seems a weird (and time wasting and confusing) thing to have to do, with questions like what happens if you install both in one org hanging there.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [accepted answer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008u75IAA):

> Yes one application can be listed in both Japanese and English AppExchange. But when building the application you have make it support multi-languages by using Custom labels and translations
>
> Given below is the procedure list single application in Japanese and English AppExchange
>
> 1. Press upload button where application was develop and packaged.
> 2. If you go to Japanese AppExchange and enter the user name and password of application's org you can list the application in Japanese AppExchange.
> 3. If you go to English AppExchange and enter the user and password of application's org you can list it in English AppExchange.
>
> Following is an example for 2 such listing of one application.
>
> Japanese
>
> https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchangejp/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HoagEAC
>
> English
>
> https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchange/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HoarEAC

I think the wording is to suggest that you cannot have the same package listed on the AppExchange multiple times in the same region. However, to be sure, I would directly contact partnersupport@salesforce.com for confirmation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get my colleague who is working on this to follow this recipe. (Our app has the multiple languages build in.) I note that that answer is from 2010, and presently those links are broken, so fingers crossed that all is good here.

Answer (score 2):

In response to my case, I got the following response:

> Please note, there is a restriction that the same managed package
> version cannot be linked to both Global AppExchange site (English) and
> Japanese AppExchange site.
>
> The information can be found in the Pre-requesite located in the
> document I shared (https://partners.salesforce.com/0693A0000091Ai5).
>
> To workaround please create a new managed package version which will
> be linked to Japanese AppExchange site.

We created a second package and could then see the package available in the app tab.